# Making edits should remove close flags

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I think the "Unclear what you are asking" caused close flags may be removed when the OP makes the question more clear by appending details, code, etc. to make the question clear.

Or, the system might tell the voters that the question is still unclear after an edit, and want them to re-vote the flag.

---

OK, so many objections for notifications, other possible solution:

What about giving some other user the permission to remove your close flag? When some user notices that the flag is useless after the OP's update, can some other user delete your flag?

Think it like some other user improves your edit.

Comment: Voting against this proposal. There are too many pointless edits, that get approved, for this to work. If the edit and review system worked better, I'd be willing to reconsider.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Then you'd still get notifications form edits where the OP just changed something minor about his post.

Comment: Short of dupe-hammering - it takes 5 users to close/re-open a question. Who would this "some other user" be with such a permission? (And how would that be an improvement over the existing method?)

Comment: re: your edit. That already exists. Its called reopening. Any 5 users above 3k reputation or any one moderator can reopen any closed question.

Comment: The original proposal could be easily abused.  Ask for something completely off-topic.  Wait for close votes.  Make a minor edit every couple of minutes.  Voila; no way to close question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> *"Oh, I just got 4 close flags / votes. Let me make a trivial edit to get rid of them!"*

I'm not very fond of this idea.

I'm not interested in receiving dozens of notifications for all the posts I once flagged, that get edited, either.

---

In regards to your suggestion about allowing "some" user to remove your vote:

**Heck no.** Nobody has the right to remove **my** vote. Not even SO staff.
SO staff can overrule whatever the community does (re-open / undelete questions, etc), but they can't make the votes disappear.

"Normal users" can *vote* to re-open or undelete questions already. There's no need to add something like that.

Comment: But even the OP improves the question, the flagger might reconsider and remove that flag, but in this society, this almost never happens.

Comment: Close votes result in the question being closed, or the question being left open. If it's left open, the votes will eventually expire. If it's closed, an edit will push the question into the review queue, with re-opening as one of the possible results.

Comment: Updated and added some other opinion.

Comment: I updated my answer as well, @TahaPaksu.

Comment: @Cerbrus Technically speaking, SO developers could. But they wouldn't.

Comment: I agree they _could_, but that still doesn't mean they're allowed to. (Or even would, indeed).

Comment: @Cerbrus, why? then you shouldn't allow other users to edit your post either?

Comment: Editing a post is meant to be an possibility to _improve_ that post. Undoing votes is just silencing opposition. There's nothing constructive about it. Forget about transparency.

Comment: @TahaPaksu Its also important to note that when someone edits my posts, my original post is still preserved. The revision never gets deleted and only in very specific cases edited. Everyone can see it. Removing my votes would be something else entirely, and something I never want to see happen.

Comment: Ok, you're right. Should I delete this post?

Comment: @TahaPaksu No need to delete it (don't let downvotes on Meta.SO worry you; they don't indicate quality on questions; they indicate agreement/disagreement.

Comment: when a question is voted to close for the wrong reason and isn't the root of the real question, then IMHO it requires a moderator's attention. I recently answered a question that only in comments was the real question revealed, and the OP edited accordingly. I solved the question and asked for the votes to close from a possible duplicate be removed but was declined. I feel that wasn't handled properly and moderators should remove them.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe I've become jaded but in the vast majority of cases where OP edits a closed question or a question pending close votes the edits are meaningless and do nothing to clarify the question. Questions that get meaningful edits can be flagged for reopening. These will then go into a Reopen Queue, and can be asessed by people capable of reopening questions.

I do not want to be pinged on edits, the reopeners can deal with that judgement.

I do not want my close votes or a closed status to be automatically removed. We have enough OPs as is that understand nothing when it comes to asking good questions.

If this was to be implemented, people everywhere would make meaningless edits to every question of themselfes everytime it is closed to reopen it instantly. That would render close voting useless.

And most importantly: Deciding wether or not your question is of sufficient quality and/or clear is not your call. There is a reason we disallow voting on your own posts.

**About your edit:**

How about **absolutely not**. 5 Users can already overrule my decisions to close a question, but the fact that I voted for it (my vote) should stay. I stand by these votes and other users have a right to know them if action results from them.

Answer (score 3):

> I think the "Unclear what you are asking" caused close flags may be removed when the OP makes the question more clear by appending details, code etc. to make the question clear.

This is what we have the reopen votes and queue for.  If the OP edited the question after the question was closed then it will automatically enter the queue and if enough people feel it is good it will get reopened.  If the question was never closed and it has been edited into a good question then it should not be closed and in 14 days the close votes will have aged off and no longer be on the question.

> Or, the system might tell the voters that the question is still unclear after edit, and want them to re-vote the flag.

There are to many minor or posted edits that happen to closed question.  I do not want to have a notification for each edit that happens.  That would drive me crazy seeing all of those notifications.

> What about giving some other user the permission to remove your close flag? When some user notices that the flag is useless after the OP's update, can some other user delete your flag?

Again, let it go through the reopen process or let the votes age away.  Another point is just because it may be clear for you does not mean it is now clear for me.

If your concern is that not enough improved questions are getting opened you can also ask on meta to get a question reopened or you can come into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and ask a [reopen-pls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reopen-pls) request.  We may or may not act on it (as users individually judge each request), but it will get the post in front of more eyeballs.